How to make a map of references with the key/value constrained to the lifetime of a closure?
I am trying to create a container that holds references for a limited period of time, constrained by the life of a closure.
My hope is to create an API like this:
let mut refs = TempRefMap::<String, &usize>::new();
let (tx, rx) = channel::<(String, Sender<()>)>();

// Worker that will read keys when notified that a value is available
thread::spawn(move || {
  while let Ok(key, tx_done) = rx.recv() {
    // assume refs is an Arc<Mutex>, perhaps internally
    let value: &usize = refs.get_ref(&key).unwrap();
  
    // Do work
    println!("{}", value);

    // Notify that work is done
    tx_done.send(()).unwrap();
  }
});

// Insert reference into the map and tell the worker it's available
refs.insert_ref("key".to_string(), &42, || {
  // Channel to notify when worker is done
  let (tx_done, rx_done) = channel::<()>();

  // Tell worker the value is available
  tx.send(("key".to_string(), tx_done)).unwrap();

  // Wait for worker to finish
  rx_done.recv().unwrap();

  // key is removed at the end of closure
});

I'm aware I can use an Rc<T> rather than a &T to manage multiple references - however I'd like to avoid that if possible because this use only occurs in one place and changing my application to an Rc would pollute a large portion of the codebase to accommodate this one use case. I'd assume there are performance implication to using an Rc here as well as this will run millions of times a second.
I'm okay with building this container using unsafe Rust - though I am unsure how to use unsafe Rust in this context.
I have tried building a type from this:
struct TempRefMap<K, V> {
  values: HashMap<K, &V>,
}

impl<K: Hash + Eq + PartialEq, V> TempRefMap<K, V> {
  fn new() -> Self {
    Self {
      values: HashMap::new()
    }
  }

  fn insert_ref(&mut self, key: K, value: &V, callback: impl FnOnce()) {
    self.values.insert(key.clone(), value);
    callback();
    self.values.remove(&key);
  }

  fn get_ref(&mut self, key: K) -> Option<&V> {
    self.values.get(&key)
  }
}

But I have various lifetime issues with storing an &V. I have tried to dereference the value unsafely and storing the value.
fn insert_ref(&mut self, key: T, value: &V, callback: impl FnOnce()) {
  let v = unsafe { *value };
  self.values.insert(key.clone(), v);
  callback();
  self.values.remove(&key);
}

However I don't think unsafe works like that (I'm not super experienced with unsafe)

Don't. This just opens the door to so many potential issues. You can't do what you're currently trying in a safe way, even attempting to do it like that, opens the door to soundness holes, e.g. what happens if the owning thread panics, while the reading thread is running. So even if you don't want to use Arc, then that is the safer alternative

Yeah, it looks like all roads point to change my code so that my &Value is an Arc<Value> and taking it back out into a Value after it's done

"I am trying to create a container that holds references for a limited period of time, constrained by the life of a closure." really sounds like an XY Problem to me. Why do you need this over something else? What's the actual problem you're trying to resolve here?

@Kraigolas You're right, the solution was to make the underlying store (a DashMap<String, Value>) available to consumers rather than trying to find a hacky way to store references locally. I'm glad Rust fought me on this because it ended up saving me from myself :)
